# Using nx run-many shows: Another process, with id ..., is currently running ngcc

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

We are having an NX monorepo with 10+ Angular apps and 150+ libs. Our CI server is running all builds in docker containers using Ubuntu. We are storing and sharing the computation caching across all build agents. We are now using nx affected:apps to detect for which apps the builds need to run and nx affected:libs to create a list of affected libraries, for each app. This approach enable us to run distributed builds. We now have a dedicated build plan for each app and its dependent libraries.

So, we are using nx affected, computation caching and distributed builds but we are still struggling with long build durations because of the large number of tests we need to run.

The next step we took was to use nx run-many to run those tests in parallel but this did not work for us. Even with 2 parallel processes we see the following error:

**Another process, with id ..., is currently running ngcc. Waiting up to 250s for it to finish.**

We have tried all the workarounds without any success
If I run the same command inside the same docker container but running on my local machine, everything works ok.

So, instead of reducing the build time, this approach is adding to the total build duration (if we want to run 4 parallel processes we need to wait for 16min before the tests actually start).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with NX throwing  `ngcc is already running`

What helped me was to set the flag parallel.

from:

`npx nx run-many --target=build --prod --all`

to:

`npx nx run-many --target=build --prod --all --parallel=1`

Comment: actually, for me the problem started when I started to use the --parallel flag. Which kinda make sense as there are parallel tests running now which might require running the ivy compiler. The problem is that this warning is shown on consequent test runs.

Comment: at first i was using parallel=5 but Jenkins was sometimes having a bad day and would throw `ngcc ...` so i've removed the parallel flag, but as it turns out nx is using parallel=3 as default, and you can see it in the log for a short time something in the lines `building projects in parallel` (which is cleared from the console when done)

Comment: same symptoms on a GitLab Job/VM, then setting `parallel=1` solved these... but job duration went through the roof; nevertheless, thanks for pointing out the `--parallel=1` option!